# How can I print elements from same list in one line in 2 colors?

Tags: python

I am tring to program Game in Life in python. My output looks like this. I don't really want to use any modules (those where installations and download is needed) because my old teacher said that if he won't be able to start program he will fail you.

That is why I need basic python. I would love to change colors of my "1" to green to make it easy to spot changes while program is working. I heard about `colorama`, but I am not sure how to make it possible to choose every "1" from my list and paint it without changes in output besides colors.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does this help you: [how-to-print-colored-text-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-in-python)?

Comment: `curses` is built into Python now, have you looked into that? https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Comment: I dont think it helps me much, or I am just to stupid to get answear. I would like for example in 2d list [0,0,1][0,1,1][1,0,1] paint  green every "1" or "0" without destroying order in list.

Comment: Using `colorama` would require downloading and installing it first.